# Get twitter user username or id from twitter url

Tags: php, twitter

I only have the twitter url of person  like **http://twitter.com/#!/tomcruise**

I am using an Wrapper class around the Twitter API for PHP where a function userTimeline(user recent tweets etc) can be retrevied only by its id or username, but I have only the url.  Is there anything where I can retreive the username or id ?

I am using this [wrapper class](http://www.boxuk.com/upload/class.twitter.php.txt)  for twitter api

Comment: Isn't the last segment of the url (tomcruise in this case) actually the username?

Comment: @eZakto Yes. Instead of using any regex, I want to know whether any other ways twitter api will give the username

Comment: If you only have the url, you expect something like making an api call to somewhere, sending the url and retrieve the username/id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use regex to extract the username from the URL. Even if you were to pass that URL to some service that would extract the username for your, the chances are it would just use regex.

Here's a regex that will match the username from a twitter URL (with or without [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HashBang))

```
(?<=/)([\w]+?)$
```

I'm not really conversed with the Twitter API but I think you can use the [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) API call to get an ID from a username.

Hopefully that should be everything you need to get what you want done.

Comment: Regex is working fine, but I get two matches of username in url i.e `Array
(
    [0] => tomcruise
    [1] => tomcruise
)
` How to append an `@` to above regex as `@tomcruise` ?